# How to take cover_photo from Facebook in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to get the user's cover photo from Facebook but I have some problems...here is my code

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var  name : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sesso: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var immagineProfilo : UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var immagineCopertina: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil)
        {
            print("Not logged in..")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Logged in..")
        }

        let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
        loginButton.center = CGPointMake(80, 100)
        loginButton.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(loginButton)

    }

    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)
    {
        if error == nil
        {
            print("Login complete.")
             /*  let protectedPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
            let protectedPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: protectedPage)

            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

            appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = protectedPageNav*/

            if let _ = result.token{
                //Get user acces token
                let _:FBSDKAccessToken=result.token

                print("Token = \(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)")

                print("User ID = \(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().userID)")


            }

            //Show user information
            let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"name,picture, email, gender, pic_cover"])

            graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                if ((error) != nil)
                {
                    // Process error
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
                else
                {
                    let imgURLCoverPhoto = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().userID)/pic_cover?
                    let imgURLCover = NSURL(string: imgURLCoverPhoto)
                    let imageDataCoverPhoto = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURLCover!)
                    let imageCoverPhoto = UIImage(data: imageDataCoverPhoto!)
                    self.immagineCopertina.image = imageCoverPhoto
                    let imgURLString = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().userID)/picture?width=10000"
                    let imgURL = NSURL(string: imgURLString)
                    let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL!)
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                    self.immagineProfilo.image = image

                    print("fetched user: \(result)")
                     self.name.text = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString as String
                    self.name.text = result.valueForKey("gender") as! NSString as String


                }
            })


        }
        else
        {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!)
    {
        print("User logged out...")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: you have some problems... which problems?

Comment: In the console appear -error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example using fb sdk in swift. The docs did help but they're not a copy paste kind of example..
I needed to get the cover photo of a page so in the graphPath I used page id. This parameter can be easily changed to fit users / events / etc...

```
let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "\\(page.id)?fields=cover", parameters: [
  "access_token": "your_access_token"
], HTTPMethod: "GET")
request.startWithCompletionHandler({(connection , result , error) in
  if ((error) != nil) {
    print("Error in fetching cover photo for \\(page.id): \(error)", terminator: "")
  }
  else {
    if let data = result["cover"] as? NSDictionary {
      self.fetchImageFromUrl(data["source"] as! String, cb: {(image: UIImage) -> Void in
        //do something with image
      })
    }
  })

func fetchImageFromUrl(url: String, cb: (UIImage) -> Void) {
  let urlObj = NSURL(string: url)!
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: urlObj)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
      let image = UIImage(data: data!)!
      cb(image)
    });
  }
}
```

P.S - I'm a newbie in swift / ios so this code might not be the best. Comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A look at the docs helps sometimes:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#Reading
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/cover-photo/

The correct field is `cover`, not `pic_cover` as found in your code.

Comment: I tried to put cover in fields but nothing change...i think that the problem is in let imgURLCoverPhoto

Comment: Well, if you'd read the docs, you'd see that it can't be of type `UIImage` IMHO, because there's an object returned. You find the URL of the image in the `cover.source` field. And, if you change your code and you're still having problems, you should update the question. Otherwise it's just guesswork.

Comment: So in the fields i have to put cover_source or just source?